# How are the region proposals processed in Fast R-CNN during training and testing?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, object-detection

How are the region proposals processed in Fast R-CNN during training and testing?

From my understanding, during training we sample some small number (e.g. 64) of region proposals out of the ~2000 region proposals, from N randomly selected images (e.g. N = 2, giving us a mini-batch of 128 region proposals). On the other hand, during inference we use all the ~2000 region proposals.

Are the region proposals processed (by RoI pooling) one by one (sequentially)? Since they have arbitrary sizes I don't see how they could be processed in in parallel.